# What are quick, temporary solutions for displaying a physical portfolio?

Tags: portfolio

Saw a question on Twitter that got me thinking...this is probably a problem that other photographers run into.

If I have a portfolio meeting and don't want to show the usual portfolio full of prints covered in gross, plastic sleeves, what alternatives do I have? The goal is to put new prints into some kind of presentation box or 3-ring binder, but this is just a temporary solution - it needs to be something available quickly at [Samys Camera](http://www.samys.com/) or somewhere similar.

What is the best way to display a physical portfolio without using plastic sleeves?

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit 'outside the box', but how about using an iPad or some similar tablet device? You can show as many or as few photos as you want, there are no fiddly plastic sleeves, and it takes up very little space.

Comment: Exactly what I was about to suggest, Nick.

Comment: This is also what I do. I have used Macbooks to do this for years.  I just use Lightroom on slideshow mode.

Comment: Plus, the iPad still draws attention. I suspect it also can help your customer think you are technically capable and know how to handle your digital camera.

Comment: If you do go with an iPad, Datacolor's new [SpyderGallery app](http://wired.com/gadgetlab/2011/05/spydergallery-brings-color-calibration-to-the-ipad/) would be worth looking into, for accurate color display.

Comment: Just wondering, does this fit the criteria of 'physical portfolio'?

Comment: @rfusca not strictly, but that's why I added my caveat 'outside the box'. It's up to the OP whether it meets her needs; she may not have considered it as a viable solution.

Comment: I think using a tablet is a great idea..."physical portfolio" to me would be anything brought to an in-person meeting that someone can hold and browse through themselves. Technically, this means laptops would count, too, but the tactile nature of the iPad makes it much more suited to flipping through a portfolio. :) I imagine not everyone shares this opinion, but there's a huge difference to me, on many levels, between a laptop and a touch-screen tablet.

Comment: Beat me to it. I use a Surface but it get's the job done as well.